# why g element rendering outside of svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I use D3.js append g element after svg. But it, somehow, renders outside of parent svg element.

It looks like g element's container is body, but not svg element.

JS code:

```
var map = $("#map");
var mapw = map.width();
var maph = mapw;
var svg_map = d3.select("#map").append('svg').attr('width',mapw).attr('height',maph);
var g_map = svg_map.append('g').attr('transform','translate('+maph/2+','+mapw/2+')');
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: a <g> is the size of its contents always. If the contents are outside the <svg> bounds then so is the <g>

Comment: @Robert Longson i'm trying to draw the shape of us map using d3.js and put it into svg element. Is there any way i can set size of <g> equal to <svg> and put <g> in it as well?

Comment: @Robert Longson oh i got it. i just realized that i made <g> too big. after i've adjust the size, it works fine. thank you.